# Itextsharp and arabic character?

Tags: asp.net, arabic

i have use itextsharp to convert html to pdf(using asp.net C#) and its work in english characters , but when i want to convert html including arabic characters it will give me empty pdf !!

can any one help me?

Comment: I was facing this problem before, you may have a look at my question " Convert arabic"unicode" content html or xml to pdf using itextsharp " that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your font does not have glyphs for the Arabic code points. You need to embed a font that has Arabic glyphs such as arabtype.ttf.

```
string fontpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "SystemRoot" ) + "\\fonts\\arabtype.ttf";
BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont( fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED );
Font arabicFont = new Font( basefont, 10f, Font.NORMAL );
```