# ITextsharp not displaying ARABIC data when converting html table data to PDF

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext

I am making a report.following is a code and sample.I am using html table for reports.When I run the code pdf is successfully generated but Arabic is not showing.Can you guide me how can i embed Arabic in it.Can you modify my following code which shows arabic  data.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
tblid1.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80f, 80f, -2f, 35f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();

<table id="tblid1" runat="server">

<tr>

   <td>سلطانالخارج</td>

<td>مسندم</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display Unicode characters in converting Html to Pdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329863/display-unicode-characters-in-converting-html-to-pdf)

Comment: I am not gentrating html using string builder.My html is in .aspx page not in the code behind file

Comment: Doesn't matter. iTextSharp has no concept of ASP.Net, controls, code-behind, etc. You need to feed it a string that represents valid HTML. You are also using the old and no longer maintained HTMLWorker, I would recommend that you switch to XMLWorker.

Comment: Is XMLWORKER can convert html to pdf?

Comment: Yes. Although the name is deceiving it is where all HTML and CSS parsing efforts are being placed.

Comment: I am add refrence of iTextSharp.xml  in visual studio for xmlWorker.A messagebox appear itextsharp.xml could not be added which refrence I will use for using in asp.net c#

Comment: using iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser; BUT xml worker not found

Comment: check this question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Answer (score 1):

You would need to embed a font into your pdf that supports arabic glyphs.

```
string fontpath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "SystemRoot" ) + "\\fonts\\arabtype.ttf";
BaseFont basefont = BaseFont.CreateFont( fontpath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED );
Font arabicFont = new Font( basefont, 10f, Font.NORMAL );
```

Answer found in thread: [Itextsharp and arabic character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472384/itextsharp-and-arabic-character)

**EDIT**: This is how I would do it based on the examples I could find and what you're trying to accomplish:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string htmlString = client.DownloadString(url);
}

FontFactory.Register("c:/windows/fonts/arabtype.TTF"); 
StyleSheet style = new StyleSheet();
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "face", "%NAME OF ARABIC FONT%");
style.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80f, 80f, -2f, 35f)) {
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
    document, Response.OutputStream
  );
  document.Open();
  foreach(IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
      new StringReader(htmlString), style))
  {
    document.Add(element);
  }
}
```

Note that you would need to ensure you are registering the correct TTF file that contains the encoding for arabic characters and that you would need to replace %NAME OF ARABIC FONT% with the name of the font you're using, and replace %VARIABLE CONTAINING YOUR RAW HTML% with the actual HTML.

Comment: but how can i use arabicFont variable.I am direct convert html to pdf not making a cell.If you have example please share

Comment: Acctually i want to fetch the data of html table through id and want to render it itext sharp.My all html is in front end .aspx file not in the code behind file

Comment: tblid.ToString() is not work in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
      new StringReader(tblid.ToString()), style))

Comment: Then you would read your html in to a string with something like: using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   string s = client.DownloadString(url);
}

Comment: replace %NAME OF ARABIC FONT% with the name of the font you're using

Comment: this is not downloading

Comment: How can i download this

Comment: You still need to write the code and update it to implement an actual font that has the encoding you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arialFontPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF");
            FontFactory.Register(arialFontPath);
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(arialFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
            iTextSharp.text.Font FontAr = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf);
            iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(arialFontPath);

StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.FONTSIZE, "16");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.COLOR, "navy");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.FONTWEIGHT, "bold");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.P, HtmlTags.INDENT, "30px");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

 List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), styles);
                for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
                {
                    pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
                }
```

this piece of code worked for me, arabic language works perfect in this,
just pass your html text to my **htmltext** Variable..

Hopefully it will work fine.